# user_likes scope issue in facebook php api

Tags: php, facebook

This is my scopes:

```
$required_scope     = 'public_profile, publish_actions, email, read_stream, manage_pages, user_birthday, user_likes';
```

This is the login part:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/fb/autoload.php"; //include autoload from SDK folder

//import required class to the current scope
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id , $app_secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);

$login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => $required_scope ) );
```

This is the code when I get some results:

```
$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($user_profile); echo "</pre>";
```

My code works fine. I am getting information about my profile. This is result of the var_dump:

```
    ["favorite_athletes"]=>
        array(9) {
          [0]=>
          object(stdClass)#9 (2) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(15) "184161078291195"
            ["name"]=>
            string(15) "Adriana Nechita"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(stdClass)#10 (2) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(15) "745037222223542"
            ["name"]=>
            string(13) "Simona  Halep"
          }
          [2]=>
          object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(16) "1429782880606166"
            ["name"]=>
            string(18) "Iasmin Latovlevici"
          }
    ....... until 8
          [8] 
    }
    ["favorite_teams"]=>
    array(6) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#18 (2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(15) "822633781141031"
        ["name"]=>
        string(18) "FC Bayern MÃ¼nchen"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#19 (2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(15) "361595103896895"
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "Football legends"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(stdClass)#20 (2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(11) "86037497258"
        ["name"]=>
        string(21) "Chelsea Football Club"
      }
.......
```

What I really don't understand why the var_dump shows me my favorite athletes and teams. I liked a lot of stuff on facebook. Why it shows me the 2 of these? Another question: Where is the rest of them ? Where is my favorite blogs, news, brands ?

Comment: what you are seeing are your favorite sports from your profile page and it may have something to do with how many levels of var_dump are actually displayed , take a look at these links [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and [graphobject](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0)

Comment: the var_dump it is displayed one time. After  I changed the /me into /me/likes as @luschn suggested,  it shows me 24 object of what i liked, but not all of them. Why ?

Comment: var_dump is limiting the output for reasons i cant tell yet , try using print_r() or var_debug()

Comment: I tried. It is the same , it returns me 24 objects

Comment: what makes you think it should return more than 24 objects ? and you can try me/albums to check if it returns the same number of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t see it anywhere in your code, so i assume you did not use the correct endpoint to get the likes:

```
/me/likes
```

API Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes

If all the likes don´t show up, you probably need to implement paging to get the next batch: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

...because Facebook limits the number of results, the default is 25. Not sure why you get 24, maybe you are looking at the array id and not the amount (0-24 > 25).

You can also increase the limit:

```
/me/likes?limit=100
```

Comment: well, this returns me 24 objects, for instance I liked this page: https://www.facebook.com/Cazare.Carei.Strand.Termal?fref=ts . It does not show in the var_dump. Why? I don't believe that the number of 24 represents the total numbers of pages that i liked.

Comment: i´ve added more information about that in my answer. "paging" is the keyword.

Comment: you are right, there is 25 from (0 - 24). It shows me an object paging->next. The idea is I want to add each of like page into my db. Do I have to access each time the value from the object->next ? There is no any other solution to access all of them in one piece ?

Comment: yes, you have to implement paging - or use the limit parameter, but there is a certain max value for that and afaik it is a bit buggy.

Comment: I don't know the right syntax, but is there smth like this : /me/likes?limit=200 ? and this should return me 200 objects

Comment: yes, just try it. but i found that a limit of more than 100 can lead to many problems. i highly suggest using paging only - after all you need paging anyway, because you can never be sure that there are not more than 200 likes.

Comment: one more question  :D : Can I make a filter in liked pages ? For instance: how can I get all of the liked pages which is in a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your account check you have any favorite blogs, news, brands because you should have something in your fb account then only that will be return to you.
for checking use facebook graph API.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

Comment: I don't know how to search after this page: https://www.facebook.com/Cazare.Carei.Strand.Termal?fref=ts . In which category should I include it . There is no any hotels Node